# canvas, which is more functional?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I came across an interesting question when declaring a `canvas` to work with.

I've seen it declared preemptively in the html like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

and then worked with in in a script like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Manipulations
```

**Or**

I've seen it created and worked with in a script like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.attr('id', 'myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Manipulations
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Is there any benefit to doing it the second way, is it just a stylistic difference dependent on the preference of the programmer?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how you are using the `canvas`. There was once I have to draw things on the go, so I just create a `canvas` and I didn't even append it to the DOM.

Comment: I don't quite understand. So you drew a bunch of objects on a canvas, then didn't append it because you didn't want them to be displayed?

Comment: I'm not sure where you saw this code and was second case really necessary but if I was writing something: I would use 1st code fragment for all the cases where I have well defined page structure (read as "almost everywhere") and 2nd code fragment where page is very dynamic and when you need to add/remove/modify page layout on the fly.

Comment: @Wold - Yes. I didn't display it because I have other uses for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both uses correspond to a quite different scenario :
A) you've done a nice web site, with various component, one of which is a canvas.
In this case it's way more easy to decide of the location and size of the canvas at design time, and retrieve it by id.
B) you're building a game or application that is based only on a single canvas.
No need to bother with the html file, building the canvas in the code is more handy. ( you have anyway to set its size/margin(for centering)/css size(for hiDpi/or to lower the resolution) ) .

Answer (score 1):

**First scenario**

In the first scenario the browser will do all layout of the DOM including the canvas element (provided the size is properly set which it isn't in the example).

This has the benefit that the canvas is in-place when you want to start using it. This is common if you intend to use the canvas right away as a part of your layout/design or for some functionality.

It's easier to design the page with the canvas in-place if you're doing more complex stuff integrating a canvas.

**Second scenario**

The second scenario is often used when you want to produce graphics off-line not affecting the DOM. This graphics can be extracted using `toDataURL()` and inserted or saved as an image, or it can be used directly as an image source for a primary canvas, or added at a later point.

You can use the second approach to cache certain parts of a draw operation; things like gradients which can be costly performace wise, dynamically created sprite-sheets, complex drawings of different sizes, processing of for example video/webcam or for compositing and other optimization reasons and so forth.

It can also be that you at a later point need to insert or replace another DOM element with a canvas as part of a control or something similar.

Or, you simply chose one of the ways as a preference.

Or.. (add whatever I forgot to mention :) ).